# UIViewPropertyAnimator - simply stop all animations, rather than a specific one?

Tags: ios, caanimation, uiviewpropertyanimator

In `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, is there a way to just stop all `UIViewPropertyAnimator` animations?

Or perhaps simply get all current animations - then of course you could `stop` them all.

Can this be done?

Or do you really have to

- (a) do only one per `UIViewPropertyAnimator`,

and,

- (b) keep a reference to each of those?

Comment: Any update on this by any chance?

Comment: a good question @SwiftRabbit, and no nothing more !  :O

Comment: You ask “Or do you really have to keep a reference to every single animation?” How would you even get a reference to an animation, since `UIViewPropertyAnimator` doesn't return references to the animations it creates? Did you mean “keep a reference to every single **animator**?” Are you using many animators or a single animator?

Comment: "How would you even get a reference to an animation" well that's what I'm wondering - is there a way to have it spit them all out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every animation has to have atleast one UIViewPropertyAnimator instance. In order to stop the animation, we have to explicitly call `stopAnimation(_:)` on the animator instance.

A way would be to make a factory class to fetch `UIViewPropertyAnimator` instance and keep track of it in a set or array. And then use this factory class to stop or start all the animations at once. Or use one `UIViewPropertyAnimator` to perform all your animations and stop it.

Comment: As it says "Or do you really have to keep a reference to every single animation?"

Comment: either use one animator instance or track all the animator instances